# What is the recommended way to detect a consumer reaching the end of a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This is a relatively basic question but I have never fully understood what the recommended approach is. I don't think this is converged in any documentation pages - at least not as far as I have seen.

- What is the canonical or recommended way of writing a Kafka consumer application and answering the question "has the consumer read all data from the log?"

There are several potential approaches. Before discussing potential options, I will explain why this is a sensible question to want to ask in some circumstances.

#### Stateless Microservices

We usually think of Kafka in the context of stateless microservices. In such contexts, it would be an anti-pattern for any microservice process to need to know when it has reached the end of a Kafka topic log.

- Stateless Microservices are expected to continually poll for data, perform some transformation and produce some output. Nothing about them should require knowledge of the current topic position, or whether or not the consumer has reached the end.

#### Stateful Services

Things change when services become stateful, because we may need to perform some state recovery on restart. In many cases this will require reading data from a Kafka topic from the earliest available data (or maybe last commit) until the end of the topic.

- In this case it is vital that there is some way to detect reaching the end of the topic such that we know state has been restored.
- I do not consider this a design anti-pattern, however I also do not know if there is a robust way of detecting the end of topic condition.

#### Possible Approaches

1. **Detecting consumer `poll()` timeout:**

This seems like the most obvious solution. Set a timeout of perhaps 5-10 seconds and wait for the consumer `poll()` function to timeout and return "none".

- This doesn't seem like a robust approach, as I would assume (the documentation doesn't explicitly say) that `poll()` might timeout because of a network issue rather than because the end has been reached. `poll()` can return an error state, but this method will only work if the only circumstances under which `poll()` can return "none" is if there is no data available and not for some other issue like a transient network problem.

Can this be guaranteed?

- There is a further problem. How long should `poll()` wait for? We might set a latency of 60 seconds just to be more certain that there is no data available, but then this introduces a long artificial delay as part of a startup process.

2. **Comparing the message offset with a cached copy of all topic and partition offsets.**

I previously used this approach in a production system, but it involves a lot of heavy logic.

The idea goes like this:

- Start up a consumer, consume a single event (to make sure it is connected) and then query the topic metadata to get a list of partition maximum offsets for all subscribed topics.
- Continue to read events from the consumer, and cache the returned offset values for each partition.
- Test to see if for every partition whether the cached offset is equal to or greater than the maximum value found when the initial query was performed.
- This logic involves some nasty edge cases, such as when a topic or partition has no data.
- In general, not a great approach but maybe better than relying on `poll()` timing out.

#### Is there a better method?

This seems like the kind of thing that anyone who is working with stateful services would need to be able to do.

I would guess there is a better approach but I don't currently know what it might be.

Comment: You can check consumer lag or high watermarks. Compare the current polled offset to the data from the broker... Some kafka clients (librdkafka, Python) also throw EOF when at end of partitions, but continue to poll

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the comment. Which part of the API would you recommend using to do this. The way I have done it before, as described in the question under (2) is to use - from memory - I believe it was a topic metadata query call? It was a really quite hideous piece of logic.

Comment: Depends on what's available. I don't think caching the end offsets once is a good option in an active topic; I've always used kafka assuming that a topic will not become idle. In Java, a JMX Mbean is registered with lag information. Micrometer / Spring Actuator can make that easier to query than using JMX API. You can also export lag data to external Prometheus server for the whole cluster or use Burrow, then query either with HTTP clients. As far as where in the code to check, it'd have to be while polling. I'm not sure there's any better way to do it.